# SSIS Transfer Database Task - Login Conflict

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

(SSIS - SQL SERVER 2008 R2) 
I am trying to transfer a copy of several Production databases to a training environment. They need to be copied automatically at the end of every month and I am required by the client to use SSIS.

I set up an SSIS package using the "Transfer Database Task" to copy and replace the db in the training environment using "Online mode" (Can't take down production during this process) When running the package I get the following error:

"The login already has an account under a different user name."

The login is a windows user and the sid's match between the servers. I tried using the "Transfer Logins Task" which worked for a sql server login but the login it is choking on is the one I am using to run the etl

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the SQL Login on the destination server is mapped to a different user.

See if this link from [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35225/the-login-already-has-an-account-under-a-different-user-name) is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Mike, It didn't solve the problem but I now have a better understanding and will add some detail to the question above.

Comment: Thanks. It's too bad about the SSIS requirement. I think this would be best done in SQL with a backup and restore script.